# Altium shortcut keys stopped working

Tags: altium

Recently for no reason at all some Altium shortcuts have stopped working, although not in all modes.
For example, while placing anything in the schematic mode, pressing TAB no longer jumps to the properties panel but in PCB mode it still works.
Another example, when moving a component, pressing X or Y no longer flips the component as it used to (only in the schematic mode, in PCB mode it still works fine). Instead X popups up the menu in the attached image, while Y does nothing.

[image: pressing x while dragging a component]

I tried restoring the settings from Tools -> Preferences -> Set to default (all) with no success.

Tested on Altium 20 and recently I upgrade to 21 with the problem persisting.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'd ask my Altium FAE.

Comment: Obviously a question best asked of their support. If you Ctrl-left click on a drop-down menu item and scroll down to TAB (attempting to assign it as a shortcut key) it will tell you if it is otherwise assigned. Don't forget to restore to to <none>(!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did now have exact this problem, andf solved it doing this:
Tools > Preferences > System > View > Desktop > Reset

[image]

Comment: Interesting how an unrelated setting affects another setting. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem and I solved it:

1. Toolbar right click and "customize":

[image]

2.

[image]

3. Set "Shortcut Table" to true

[image]